# Sharepoint Services beginner question

Tags: sharepoint

I want to start developing on share point. I already have experience with VS.NET 2005 and VS.NET 2008.

My question is, If I download Sharepoint Services 3.0 to my virtual server 2003 will I be able to start learning to develop in share pint?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, WSS (windows sharepoint services 3.0) can be installed to Windows Server 2003. You should also download the WSS Developer SDK:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=05E0DD12-8394-402B-8936-A07FE8AFAFFD&displaylang=en

Also the VSeWSS tools for VS2008 to deploy to SharePoint would also be useful for a beginner:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=b2c0b628-5cab-48c1-8cae-c34c1ccbdc0a&DisplayLang=en

There are more advanced tools like SPVisualDev and WSPBuilder on CodePlex but when the time comes to need them, you'll know.

-Oisin

Comment: Can WSS be installed using sqlexpress

Comment: @roncansan: yes. it can be used with sqlexpress (if this is what you mean)